# nginx match no found when using a query string

Tags: nginx

I am a little stuck with Nginx not behaving as I expect it to?

When making a curl request to `curl -I http://example.com/schedule/ajax.php` I get the expected output of `HTTP/1.1 200 OK`

However, when I add a query string it fails `curl -I http://example.com/schedule/ajax.php?m=item` with `no matches found: http://example.com/schedule/ajax.php?m=item`

Additionally:

- this project has Drupal which is fully functioning and its Nginx root is at `/` (as
  in Drupal's index.php file is in /`app/web/`)
- then the `schedule` directory is not a Drupal and if files are in `/app/web/schedule/`
- the ajax.php is a special case as all other requests are processed by
  index.php so for example `http://example.com/schedule/view` is
  processed be `/schedule/index.php` (yes not `/app/web/index.php`)
- so the short version is `/schedule` is not Drupal but `/` is

So my question is why do requests to `http://example.com/schedule/ajax.php?m=item` fail?

My nginx config is

```
server {
  listen ${NGINX_LISTEN:-8080} default_server;

  include /etc/nginx/helpers/*.conf;

  root /app/${WEBROOT:-};
  index  index.php;

  ## rewriting /index.php to / because after https://www.drupal.org/node/2599326
  ## autocomplete URLs are forced to go to index.php
  rewrite ^/index.php / last;

  location /schedule/ajax.php {
    add_header X-debug-message-ajax "a: $args q:$query_string" always;
    #return 403;
    try_files $uri /schedule/ajax.php?$args;
  }

  location /schedule/ {
    ## Disallow access to any dot files, but send the request to wordpress
    location ~* /\. {
      try_files /dev/null @php;
    }

    ## Direct Access to .php files is not alled and is sent to wordpress instead
    location ~* ^.+\.php$ {
      try_files /dev/null @php;
    }

    ## Try to find a file with given URL, if not pass to wordpress
    try_files $uri /schedule/$uri/ /schedule/index.php?$args;
  }

  ## The 'default' location.
  location / {
    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/drupal/location_prepend*.conf;

    ## Do not allow access to .txt and .md unless inside sites/*/files/
    location ~* ^(?!.+sites\/.+\/files\/).+\.(txt|md)$ {
      deny all;
      access_log off;
      log_not_found off;
    }

    ## Replicate the Apache <FilesMatch> directive of Drupal standard
    ## .htaccess. Disable access to any code files. Return a 404 to curtail
    ## information disclosure.
    location ~* \.(engine|inc|install|make|module|profile|po|sh|.*sql|.*sql\.gz|theme|twig|tpl(\.php)?|xtmpl|yml)(~|\.sw[op]|\.bak|\.orig|\.save)?$|^\/(\.(?!well-known).*|Entries.*|Repository|Root|Tag|Template|composer\.(json|lock))$|^\/#.*#$|\.php(~|\.sw[op]|\.bak|\.orig|\.save)$ {
      deny all;
      access_log off;
      log_not_found off;
    }

    ## Expiring per default for four weeks and one second, Drupal will overwrite that if necessary
    expires ${NGINX_DEFAULT_EXPIRES:-2628001s};

    ## Disallow access to any dot files, but send the request to Drupal
    location ~* /\. {
      try_files /dev/null @drupal;
    }

    ### Directives for installing drupal.
    location ~* ^(/install.php|/core/install.php) {
      try_files /dev/null @php;
    }

    ## Direct Access to .php files is not allowed and is sent to Drupal instead
    location ~* ^.+\.php$ {
      try_files /dev/null @drupal;
    }

    ## Try to find a file with given URL, if not pass to Drupal
    try_files $uri @drupal;

  }

  ## Main Drupal Location
  location @drupal {
    add_header X-debug-message-drupal "1" always;
    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/drupal/location_drupal_prepend*.conf;

    include        /etc/nginx/fastcgi.conf;
    fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_NAME        /index.php;
    fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME    $realpath_root/index.php;
    fastcgi_pass   ${NGINX_FASTCGI_PASS:-php}:9000;

    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/drupal/location_drupal_append*.conf;
  }

  ## PHP Location.
  ## Warning: This allows to execute any PHP files, use with care!
  location @php {
    add_header X-debug-message-php "$realpath_root : $fastcgi_script_name : $args" always;
    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/drupal/location_php_prepend*.conf;

    include        /etc/nginx/fastcgi.conf;
    fastcgi_pass   ${NGINX_FASTCGI_PASS:-php}:9000;

    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/drupal/location_php_append*.conf;
  }

  ## Trying to access private files directly returns a 404.
  location /sites/default/files/private/ {
    internal;
  }

}
```

Comment: That's actually an error from your shell. Its trying to expand the `?` wildcard. Place the URL in quotes.

Comment: Thanks, Richard ... can't believe I missed that.

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out in the comments the issue was not with Nginx it was actually an error in my curl request.